# Where is the other half of the _Default partial class that is created when you create a webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When you add a webform, you get a file called Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Where is the other half of it?

Answer (score 3):

The other half is the Default.aspx.designer.cs file which includes all the controls you've added to the ASP.Net page.

Comment: Is there a way I can view what's in this file?

Comment: Yep, locate it in VS right click and do 'View Code'.  Failing that find it on your filesystem and open it in something nice like Notepad++ :)

Comment: There are only three files in my project file - Default.aspx, Default.aspx.cs, and web.config. I am looking for Default.aspx.designer.cs yeah?